# Создать массив из значения input

Tags: javascript, jquery, динамические-массивы

Есть `<input type=text>`, в которое пользователь вписывает свое значение в формате `от-до` например `25-29` из введенного в `input` значения по нажатию кнопки нужно сформировать массив `25,26,27,28,29` и отобразить на экране в виде `checkbox` т.е так

`<input type='checkbox' value='25'>` и т.д. до конца массива. Помогите реализовать эту задачу

Comment: что у Вас уже есть?

Comment: К сожалению ничего не могу придумать

Comment: Не совсем  понял вопрос....

Comment: Пользователь снчало вводит в `input` число например `25-28` нажимает кнопку. После нажатия кнопки скрипт должен сформировать массив чисел от `25-28` и вывести на экран ввиде `<input type='checkbox' value='25'>` и т.д. до конца массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут алгоритм действий примерно следующий

1. Получаем значение из поля инпут при нажатии на кнопку (получаем значение String)
2. Парсим полученную строку:

```js
const parser = (str) => {
   const arr = [];
   const parts = str.split('-');
   // На всякий случай делаем проверку, чтобы from было меньше to
   const from = Math.min(parseInt(parts[0]), parseInt(parts[1]));
   const to = Math.max(parseInt(parts[0]), parseInt(parts[1]));
   for(let i = from; i <= to; i++){
       arr.push(i);
   }    
   return arr;
}

// Проверяем:
console.log(parser('10-22'));
```

3. Ну и дальше добавляем чекбоксы в DOM, напиример так:

```js
const arr = [11,12,13,14,15];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   $('#checkbox-wrapper').append(`<label><input type="checkbox" value="${arr[i]}"> ${arr[i]} </label>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='checkbox-wrapper'>
</div>
```

Для уменьшения ошибок ввода я бы порекомендовал начальный input разделить на два (от и до), и задал бы им type=number

Answer (score 0):

Создаете input, button и div в котором будут чекбоксы:

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<button onclick={myFunc()}>click</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Один из вариантов:

```
function myFunc() {
    // берем значение из input
    var element = document.getElementById('input').value
    // разбиваем его по знаку "-"
    var arr = element.split('-')
    // если длина массива === 2, то все ок
    if (arr.length === 2) {
        // переводим в число
        var num1 = Number(arr[0])
        var num2 = Number(arr[1])
        // если это оба числа и 1 число меньше 2 то все ок
        if (!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2) && num1 <= num2) {
            var divEl = document.getElementById('div')
            // очищаем все что внутри div
            while (divEl.firstChild) {
                divEl.removeChild(divEl.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
                // создаем чекбокс
                var checkbox = document.createElement('input')
                checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
                checkbox.value = i
                checkbox.id = 'checkbox' + i
                // создаем label для чекбокса
                var label = document.createElement('label')
                label.htmlFor = 'checkbox' + i
                label.innerHTML = 'checkbox' + i
                // добавляем в наш div
                divEl.appendChild(checkbox)
                divEl.appendChild(label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

К сожалению не знаю что у вас за условия, но при желании можно не делать проверки на isNaN, а просто запрещать ввод например символов, или на input сделать какую нибудь маску. Просто у вас не совсем очевидно что требуется